# SQL return all rows on empty parameter or exclude condition from query

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a web filter function for a database. You can enter search criteria in on a form which sends the data to a Php scripts that creates an SQL query and throws back all rows as result.

Now the question is how to create a SQL statement with possibly empty parameters (not filled in form filter options) Eventually there will be a lot of filter options so checking which ones are filled to create a specific query with IF statements will be almost impossible.

**For now** there are 3 textboxes and 3 `<select>` options. The user doesn't have to fill in everything and when pressing submit it sends all data as POST, including the empty filter options, to PhP script that creates a SQL query.

Right now that query (not all filter options are included in query yet) could look like this

`SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE "%%" AND type="Consumable" AND subtype=""`

But this won't return anything since there is no row with subtype="" they all have a value. How can I make it that if the parameter is empty it returns everything of that column. Or how can I exclude the condition from the query if an `POST` is empty, not including `AND subtype=""` in the query if parameter is empty.

Comment: It's often called such things as a Query Builder, where depending on the user input, it explodes out the fields in a generated query (as opposed to the way you described it)

Comment: @Drew Where and how can I use a Query builder? I can only find frameworks or some sort made by others.

Comment: Barmar closed the question and gave a link in the top pink/peach block. Going there, the Answer with the votes, starts by saying **Build the WHERE clause dynamically.** ... and it shows the **implode**   ... I would guess there are 500 examples under PHP on S.O.

Comment: The concept is no different in any programming language for a Query Builder